# In Perl, is there a built in way to compare two arrays for equality?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays of strings that I would like to compare for equality:

```
my @array1 = ("part1", "part2", "part3", "part4");
my @array2 = ("part1", "PART2", "part3", "part4");
```

Is there a built-in way to compare arrays like there is for scalars?
I tried:

```
if (@array1 == @array2) {...}
```

but it just evaluated each array in scalar context, and so compared the length of each array.

I can roll my own function to do it, but it seems like such a low-level operation that there should be a built-in way to do it.  Is there?

Edit: sadly, I don't have access to 5.10+ or optional components.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is the new [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @x = (1, 2, 3);
my @y = qw(1 2 3);

say "[@x] and [@y] match" if @x ~~ @y;
```

Regarding [Array::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Array::Compare):

> Internally the comparator compares the two arrays by using join to turn both arrays into strings and comparing the strings using `eq`.

I guess that is a valid method, but so long as we are using string comparisons, I would much rather use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::AllUtils qw( each_arrayref );

my @x = qw(1 2 3);
my @y = (1, 2, 3);

print "[@x] and [@y] match\n" if elementwise_eq( \(@x, @y) );

sub elementwise_eq {
    my ($xref, $yref) = @_;
    return unless  @$xref == @$yref;

    my $it = each_arrayref($xref, $yref);
    while ( my ($x, $y) = $it->() ) {
        return unless $x eq $y;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If the arrays you are comparing are large, joining them is going to do a lot of work and consume a lot of memory than just comparing each element one by one.

**Update:** Of course, one should test such statements. Simple benchmarks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Array::Compare;
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );
use List::AllUtils qw( each_arrayref );

my @x = 1 .. 1_000;
my @y = map { "$_" } 1 .. 1_000;

my $comp = Array::Compare->new;

cmpthese -5, {
    iterator => sub { my $r = elementwise_eq(\(@x, @y)) },
    array_comp => sub { my $r = $comp->compare(\(@x, @y)) },
};
```

This is the worst case scenario where `elementwise_eq` has to go through each and every element in both arrays 1_000 times and it shows:

```
             Rate   iterator array_comp
iterator    246/s         --       -75%
array_comp 1002/s       308%         --
```

On the other hand, the best case scenario is:

```
my @x = map { rand } 1 .. 1_000;
my @y = map { rand } 1 .. 1_000;
```

```
              Rate array_comp   iterator
array_comp   919/s         --       -98%
iterator   52600/s      5622%         --
```

`iterator` performance drops quite quickly, however:

```
my @x = 1 .. 20, map { rand } 1 .. 1_000;
my @y = 1 .. 20, map { rand } 1 .. 1_000;
```

```
              Rate   iterator array_comp
iterator   10014/s         --       -23%
array_comp 13071/s        31%         --
```

I did not look at memory utilization.

Comment: @Bill thank you, but the analysis is not that thorough. It does the bare minimum to teach me not to make assumptions without measurement and that in, most cases, you could do worse than `Array::Compare`.

Comment: Simple `my $i;for my $e (@$xref) {return unless $e eq $yref->[$i++];}` is far faster (v5.14.2).

Comment: Smart operator is deprecated in the Perl release 5.18, release May 2013.

Comment: @Flimm There are a few "less smart" alternatives to smart match which still do "comprehensive" matching. One of my favorites so far is [`match::simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple).

Answer (score 27):

There's [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::More)'s is_deeply() function, which will also display exactly where the structures differ, or [Test::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Deep)'s eq_deeply(), which doesn't require a test harness (and just returns true or false).

Comment: Thou shalt not `use` modules intended for testing... unless in tests.

Comment: @Arc but you can take their subroutines and repurpose them. The code is there.

Answer (score 13):

Not built-in, but there is [Array::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Array-Compare/).

This is one of the operations that's left out of the Perl core for what I believe are didactic reasons -- that is, if you're trying to do it, there's probably something wrong.  The most illustrative example of this, I think, is the absence of a core `read_entire_file` function; basically, providing that function in the core would lead people to think it's a *good idea* to do that, but instead, Perl is designed in a way that gently nudges you toward processing files line-at-a-time, which is generally far more efficient and otherwise a better idea, but novice programmers are rarely comfortable with it and they need some encouragement to get there.

The same applies here: there is probably a much better way to make the determination you're trying to accomplish by comparing two arrays.  Not *necessarily*, but probably.  So Perl is nudging you to think about other ways of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: For being such an expressive language, Perl does a great job of making you think about what you are doing.

Comment: So does providing the function `dump` in core mean it's a good idea to randomly die and leave a core dump sitting around?

Comment: @chaos - that's an interesting point.  I'm attempting to match my location in an Xml hierarchy against an array obtained from a text file.  (No XPath modules, sadly.)

Comment: I don't like `Array::Compare`, because of the way it works: it joins elements together with `"\x{07}"` as a separator, and compares the resulting strings. You can specify a different separator, but this is buggy if you cannot guarantee that a specific character won't appear in the array's input.

Comment: There's not a special `read_entire_file` because you already everything you need to for that. Unset the input record separator and read a line.

Answer (score 7):

Perl 5.10 gives you the smart match operator.

```
use 5.010;

if( @array1 ~~ @array2 )
{
    say "The arrays are the same";
}
```

Otherwise, as you said, you'll have top roll your own.

Comment: Actually, that will not tell you if the arrays are the same but if they are *comparable*.

Comment: Worse, it depends whether you use 5.10.0 or 5.10.1+. On 5.10.0 that does indeed check that the arrays are equal.

Comment: I really dislike using the term "comparable" to describe the behavior of smart matching on arrays. I automatically read it as "able to be compared" (which would be rather useless behavior) rather than as "equivalent" (which would be a much better term, IMHO).

Comment: Smart operator is deprecated in the Perl release 5.18, release May 2013.

Comment: This doesn't work because smart-match doesn't work how anyone thinks about the real task (insert JeffGoldblum meme). Try it with these two arrays: `my @array1 = ( 'abc', 'def' ); my @array2 = ( qr/abc/, 'def' );` Those "match", because it tries `$array1[0] ~~ $array2[0]`, which is `'abc' =~ /abc/`. Now, try it with `@array2 ~~ @array1`. Now it doesn't match, because order matters. And that's just a simple case where it falls over.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler solution is faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Array::Compare;
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );
use List::AllUtils qw( each_arrayref );

my @x = 1 .. 1_000;
my @y = map { "$_" } 1 .. 1_000;

my $comp = Array::Compare->new;

cmpthese -2, {
    iterator => sub { my $r = elementwise_eq(\(@x, @y)) },
    my_comp => sub { my $r = my_comp(\(@x, @y)) },
    array_comp => sub { my $r = $comp->compare(\(@x, @y)) },
};

@x = 1 .. 20, map { rand } 1 .. 1_000;
@y = 1 .. 20, map { rand } 1 .. 1_000;

cmpthese -2, {
    iterator => sub { my $r = elementwise_eq(\(@x, @y)) },
    my_comp => sub { my $r = my_comp(\(@x, @y)) },
    array_comp => sub { my $r = $comp->compare(\(@x, @y)) },
};

sub elementwise_eq {
    my ($xref, $yref) = @_;
    return unless  @$xref == @$yref;

    my $it = each_arrayref($xref, $yref);
    while ( my ($x, $y) = $it->() ) {
        return unless $x eq $y;
    }
    return 1;
}

sub my_comp {
    my ($xref, $yref) = @_;
    return unless  @$xref == @$yref;

    my $i;
    for my $e (@$xref) {
        return unless $e eq $yref->[$i++];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And result in `perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`:

```
             Rate   iterator array_comp    my_comp
iterator   1544/s         --       -67%       -80%
array_comp 4697/s       204%         --       -41%
my_comp    7914/s       413%        68%         --
               Rate   iterator array_comp    my_comp
iterator    63846/s         --        -1%       -75%
array_comp  64246/s         1%         --       -75%
my_comp    252629/s       296%       293%         --
```

Answer (score 3):

This question has turned into a very useful resource. ++ for the benchmarks and discussion.

As others have pointed out smart match feature had issues and is being phased out in its current form.  There are alternatives that are "less smart" (and so avoid the issues) and that are small, fairly fast and don't have too many non CORE dependencies.

- [`Smart::Match`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Match)
- [`match::simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple) (and [`match::smart`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::smart))
- [`Scalar::In`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::In)

You can find links to some pretty good discussions about the history of the future of `~~` by looking at a couple of [blog posts](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2012/08/ricardo-is-pushing-for-smart-match-changes.html) by @brian d foy, and the **p5p mail archive** threads [from 2011](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2011/07/msg174272.html) and [2012](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2012/08/msg190658.html) from @rjbs.

Comparing arrays can be simple and fun!

```
use v5.20;   
use match::smart; 
my @x = (1, 2, 3);       
my @y = qw(4 5 6);    
my @z = qw(4 5 6);   
say \@x |M| \@y ? "[\@x] and [\@y] match": "no match";  
say \@y |M| \@z ? "[\@y] and [\@z] match": "no match";

__END__                              
@y and @z match, @x and @y do not
```

... especially fun if the array is simple. But an array can be a complicated thing, and sometimes you want different kinds of information from the results of the comparison. For that, [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Compare) can make fine tuned comparison easier.

Comment: best smart match joke has to go to @rjbs for: "<fellow> ..."  :-)  See the p5p posts for context.

Comment: `match::simple` can't compare arrays. With `my @x = (1, 2, 3)` and `my @y = (4, 5, 6)`, `@x |M| @y` is true, since the operands get evaluated in scalar context. As long as number of items is equal, they match. As for array refs, [the doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple) says: "If the right hand side is an arrayref, then the operator recurses into the array, with the match succeeding if the left hand side matches any array element." Not what we need either.

Comment: `match::smart` handles that properly (recursively).

Comment: @x-yuri Thanks, fixed example.

Answer (score 3):

My core-only solution with [`List::Util::all`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#all):

```perl
use List::Util qw(all);

if (@array1 == @array2 && all { $array1[$_] eq $array2[$_] } 0..$#array1) {
    print "matched\n";
}
```

### Variations

As a subroutine:

```perl
# call me like string_array_equals([@array1], [@array2])
sub string_array_equals {
    my ($array1, $array2) = @_;

    @$array1 == @$array2 and
    all { $array1->[$_] eq $array2->[$_] } 0..$#$array1;
}
```

If you want a custom comparison:

```perl
# call me like array_equals { $a eq $b } [@array1], [@array2]
sub array_equals(&$$) {
    my ($compare, $array1, $array2) = @_;

    @$array1 == @$array2 and
    all {
        local $a = $array1->[$_];
        local $b = $array2->[$_];
        $compare->($a, $b);
    } 0..$#$array1;
}
```

At this point, `all` doesn't save much space and you could just do a `for`:

```perl
# call me like array_equals { $a eq $b } [@array1], [@array2]
sub array_equals(&$$) {
    my ($compare, $array1, $array2) = @_;

    @$array1 == @$array2 or return 0;
    for (0..$#$array1) {
        local $a = $array1->[$_];
        local $b = $array2->[$_];
        $compare->($a, $b) or return 0;
    }
    1;
}
```

**Edit:** [`List::Util::first`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#first) works as a substitute on older perls (< v5.20).

```perl
use List::Util qw(first);

if (@array1 == @array2 && !defined first { $array1[$_] ne $array2[$_] } 0..$#array1) {
    print "matched\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One could use grep function in scalar context (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html#grep-BLOCK-LIST)

```perl
($#array1 == $#array2) && (0 == (grep { $array1[ $_ ] ne $array2[ $_ ] } 0..$#array1))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Data::Cmp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Cmp) is another recent option. The `cmp_data()` function operates similarly to the `cmp` operator (see [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) for `cmp` usage).

Example:

```
use 5.10;
use Data::Cmp qw/cmp_data/;

my @array1 = ("part1", "part2", "part3", "part4");
my @array2 = ("part1", "PART2", "part3", "part4");
my @array3 = ("part1", "PART2", "part3", "part4");

# sample usage 
say "1 & 2 are different" if cmp_data(\@array1, \@array2) ;
sat "2 & 3 are the same" unless cmp_data(\@array2, \@array3) ;
```

It's also possible to compare hashes and more complicated nested data structures (within reason). For a single module with no non-core dependencies, `Data::Cmp` is pretty "smart" **;-)** ... errm I mean "useful".

Answer (score 0):

If casing is the only difference, you can simply use:

```
if (lc "@array1" eq lc "@array2") {...}
```

Whereas `"@array1"` returns the same as `join ( " ", @array1 )`

Comment: Case is important in this case.  So would `if ("@array1" eq "@array2") {...}` collapse the arrays into a string and then compare the result?  Out of curiosity, how would ("a ", "b") compare to ("a", " b")?

Comment: If case is important, then leave out the lc.  ("a", "b") would be different than ("a", " b"), because the comparison is treating each array as a string.

Comment: Since controlling how information is put into an array is implicit in its existence, I've always found this to be the simplest solution.

Comment: You'd probably want to sort those arrays first, yeah?

Comment: If you're comparing them for equality, it seems to me sorting would defeat the purpose.

Comment: It will find `qw(a b)` equal to `qw(Ab)`.

Comment: Indeed, as the question indicated, the comparison needed to be case-insensitive.

Comment: @tempire: the question did not indicate that the comparison needed to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Upvoting because `if ("@array1" eq "@array2")` is a very handy way to compare, say, arrays of numbers or elements that do not contain spaces. If the elements can contain spaces, it would clearly be not reliable, such as for `("a ", "b")` vs. `("a", " b")`.

Comment: This is unreliable. You can't depend on the concatenation of all the values to tell you that each individual element is the same in isolation. Perhaps if you joined them with null bytes or some other value not in the data (but then you have to scan all the data to check for a character it doesn't contain). Then you have to manage `$"` if you are going to do this through interpolation.

Answer (score -1):

If order and duplicate values do not matter but only values equality (i.e. set comparison), you could use [`Set::Scalar`](https://p3rl.org/Set::Scalar).

It overloads common operators such as `==` or `!=`.

```
my @array1 = ("part1", "part2", "part3", "part4");
my @array2 = ("part1", "PART2", "part3", "part4");

if ( Set::Scalar->new(@array1) == Set::Scalar->new(@array2) ) {...}
```

Alternatively, there's also [`Algorithm::Diff`](https://p3rl.org/Algorithm::Diff) and [`List::Compare`](https://p3rl.org/List::Compare).

Answer (score -1):

For checking equality of two arrays try this.
In given code, if %eq_or_not has any value then both arrays are not equal otherwise they are equal.

```
my @array1 = ("part1", "part2", "part3", "part4");
my @array2 = ("part1", "PART2", "part3", "part4");

my %eq_or_not;

@eq_or_not{ @array1 } = undef;
delete @eq_or_not{ @array2 };
```

Comment: This is handy if the order and potential duplicates are irrelevant.
Giving a tentative upvote because that happens to match my current use case.
But really using this approach we're comparing sets, not arrays.

Comment: Looks great on first glance, but it doesn't correctly answer the question. Try to compare `qw(a b)` and `qw(a b c)`!

Comment: Also compare `qw(A A B)` and `qw(A B)`!

Answer (score -2):

If the only criteria is "are they equivalent or not?", and not the more complex question, "are they equivalent or not, and if they differ, how?" there are much quicker/uglier ways to do it.  For example, smash the entirety of each array into two scalars and compare those.

For example

```
my @array1 = ("part1", "part2", "part3", "part4");
my @array2 = ("part1", "PART2", "part3", "part4");

my $smash1 = join("", @array1);
my $smash2 = join("", @array2);

if ($smash1 eq $smash2)
{
  # equal
}
else
{
  #unequal
}
```

Yes, I probably just made Larry Wall cry.

Comment: You will find `qw(foo bar)` and `qw(foobar)` equal.

Comment: ++ @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil -- see my response re: perlancar's  `Data::Cmp` module. the `_cmp_data()` function seems like an appropriately exhaustive way to compare data structures. In hindsight something like Smart Match was too ambitious.

Comment: @G.Cito: Yes, it is exhaustive, especially it exhaust CPU resource.

Answer (score -2):

`if (join(",",sort @a) eq join(",",sort @b))`

if performance concern can be ignored, as mentioned several times in the threads here