# How can I compare arrays in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays

I have two arrays, `@a` and `@b`. I want to do a compare among the elements of the two arrays.

```
my @a = qw"abc def efg ghy klm ghn";
my @b = qw"def ghy jgk lom com klm";
```

If any element matches then set a flag. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Because your question is unclear, you are getting two kinds of answers: (1) those that search for pairwise matches, such as `$a[$i] eq $b[$i]`; and (2) those that search for any match, such as `$a[$i] eq $b[$j]`. What is your goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality

Comment: @Sinan: that question you marked as "possible duplicate" is not the same as this one. That is about comparing all the elements of two arrays, but this one is about finding one common element.

Comment: @Kinopiko If the arrays differ in at least one element, they are not the same. If the arrays are the same, they do not differ in elements. The accepted answer returns `0` if at least one pair are different and `1` if none are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your 2 arrays need to be written correctly.

```
@a = ("abc","def","efg","ghy","klm","ghn");
@b = ("def","efg","ghy","klm","ghn","klm");
```

Second of all, for arbitrary arrays (e.g. arrays whose elements may be references to other data structures) you can use [`Data::Compare`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Compare).

For arrays whose elements are scalar, you can do comparison using [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils) `pairwise BLOCK ARRAY1 ARRAY2`, where BLOCK is your comparison subroutine. You can emulate `pairwise` (if you don't have List::MoreUtils access) via:

```
if (@a != @b) {
    $equals = 0;
} else {
    $equals = 1;
    foreach (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++) {
        # Ideally, check for undef/value comparison here as well 
        if ($a[$i] != $b[$i]) { # use "ne" if elements are strings, not numbers
                                # Or you can use generic sub comparing 2 values
            $equals = 0;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I am not sure but [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::Compare) may always sort the lists. I'm not sure if it can do pairwise comparisons.

Comment: You are using `scalar` way too liberally for my taste.

Comment: Scalar comparison operators impose scalar context on their arguments. So, `@a == @b` is the same as `scalar(@a) == scalar(@b)` and `$i < @a` is the same as `$i < scalar(@a)`.

Comment: That was for demo readability... i almost never use scalar() in production code, for just the reason you didn't like it here. if you think it doesn't help much, I can edit it out

Comment: This is very subjective. I think extra fluff detracts from readability (otherwise, I would still be programming in Java ;-)

Comment: I haven't double checked that it works, but why wouldn't `@a = qw"abc def efg ghy klm ghn"` work? Wouldn't it just be parsed as a list inside the user-defined delineator ('`"`' in this case?) It shouldn't be any different than `qw//` or `qw||` or `qw()` or whatnot.

Comment: @Oesor - you're not using Sinan's Time::Machine module. My comment was aimed at the original wording of the question (before brian's edit) that said `my @a = "abc,def,efg,ghy,klm,ghn"`

Comment: `qw"abc def efg ghy klm ghn"` is correct.

Answer (score 7):

[List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Compare)

```
if ( scalar List::Compare->new(\@a, \@b)->get_intersection ) {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check to create an intersect function, which will return a list of items that are present in both lists. Then your return value is dependent on the number of items in the intersected list.

You can easily find on the web the best implementation of intersect for Perl. I remember looking for it a few years ago.

Here's what I found :

```
my @array1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @array2 = (2, 3, 4);
my %original = ();
my @isect = ();

map { $original{$_} = 1 } @array1;
@isect = grep { $original{$_} } @array2;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the requirement that 'if *any* element matches', use the intersection of sets:

```
sub set{
  my %set = map { $_, undef }, @_;
  return sort keys %set;
}
sub compare{
    my ($listA,$listB) = @_;
    return ( (set(@$listA)-set(@$listB)) > 0)
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged "perl". I don't want to downvote you without warning you first ...

Comment: No question is entirely language-specific. I'm sure someone can come up with a perl version of it. It also illustrates the general point.

Comment: Yes, but what if a newbie sees your answer, in this perl-tagged thread, without any notification that it isn't a Perl answer, and types it in, then wonders why it doesn't work? The only responsible thing to do with this answer is to downvote it. Sorry.

Comment: @Brad: Cheers, that looks like a nice chunk. I'm surprised there isn't a builtin/widely available module for sets...

Comment: I removed my downvote. There is still a downvote but it's not mine.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @a = split /,/, "abc,def,efg,ghy,klm,ghn";
my @b = split /,/, "def,ghy,jgk,lom,com,klm";
my $flag = 0;
my %a;
@a{@a} = (1) x @a;
for (@b) {
    if ($a{$_}) {
        $flag = 1;
        last;
    }
}
print "$flag\n";
```

Comment: Not the easiest read but I like it.

When answering a question I like explain more offbeat behavior so we learn instead of cookbooking though.

Comment: can someone explain "@a{@a} = (1) x @a;"?

Comment: it populates the keys of `%a` with the elements of `@a`, and the values are all 1. this exploits Perl's allowance of different variable types with the same name, the hash slice, and an array in scalar context. however, this code won't work for comparing arrays with non-unique values

Answer (score 1):

```
my @a = qw' abc def efg ghy klm ghn ';
my @b = qw' def ghy jgk lom com klm ';

my $flag;

foreach  my $item(@a) {
  $flag = @b~~$item ? 0 : 1;
  last if !$flag;
}
```

Note that you will need Perl 5.10, or later, to use the [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) (`~~`) .

Comment: @DVK, I dunno. I learnt this from Learning Perl. I don't need the use 5.010; statement but maybe it's only workable after Perl 5.10. I'll check it out. I'm still a Perl learner. Kindly correct me if anything went wrong :)

Comment: @DVK, the book says "Perl 5.10's smart match operator". But it looks like that I don't have to use the use 5.010; statement. Just tested it again and the use 5.010; statement is unnecessary at least with ActivePerl 5.10.0 on WinXP. But I suppose this won't work before Perl 5.10.

Comment: While I don't see any glaring newbie mistakes, I don't think this will work correctly all of the time.

Comment: Wouldn't that need `$item ~~ @b` instead? And even if wouldn't it return true if the arrays have the same elements, but in a differenr order? If not, then please explain the code!

Answer (score 1):

Brute force should do the trick for small a `n`:

```
my $flag = 0;
foreach my $i (@a) {
    foreach my $k (@b) {
        if ($i eq $k) {
            $flag = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

For a large `n`, use a hash table:

```
my $flag   = 0;
my %aa     = ();
   $aa{$_} = 1 foreach (@a);
foreach my $i (@b) {
    if ($aa{$i}) {
        $flag = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

Where a large `n` is `|@a| + |@b| > ~1000` items

Comment: If `|@a| + |@b| == 1000` it could mean `|@a| == 2 && |@b| == 998`, or |@a| == 500 && |@b| == 500`. However in the former case the number of comparisons would be 1996, while in the latter cases it would be 250000. So basically it's *not the sum*, but the *product* that is important.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should use [List::MoreUtils::pairwise](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils#pairwise). However, if for some reason you cannot, then the following sub would return a 1 for every index where the value in the first array compares equal to the value in the second array. You can generalize this method as much as you want and pass your own comparator if you want to, but at that point, just installing [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils) would be a more productive use of your time.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @a = qw(abc def ghi jkl);
my @b = qw(abc dgh dlkfj jkl kjj lkm);
my $map = which_ones_equal(\@a, \@b);

print join(', ', @$map), "\n";

sub which_ones_equal {
    my ($x, $y, $compare) = @_;
    my $last = $#$x > $#$y ? $#$x : $#$y;
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    return [ map { 0 + ($x->[$_] eq $y->[$_]) } $[ .. $last ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Perl. The 'obvious' solution:

```
my @a = qw"abc def efg ghy klm ghn";
my @b = qw"def ghy jgk lom com klm";
print "arrays equal\n"
    if @a == @b and join("\0", @a) eq join("\0", @b);
```

given "\0" not being in @a.

But thanks for confirming that there is no other generic solution than rolling your own.

Comment: So `@a == @b` is just a performance optimization, and wouldn't it be find of inefficient for arrays with many or large elements? Would it work if the elements are references for example?

Answer (score 0):

```
my @a1 = qw|a b c d|;
my @a2 = qw|b c d e|;

for my $i (0..$#a1) {
    say "element $i of array 1 was not found in array 2" 
        unless grep {$_ eq $a1[$i]} @a2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider the arrays with different order to be different, you may use [Array::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Array::Diff)

```
if (Array::Diff->diff(\@a, \@b)->count) {
   # not_same
} else {
   # same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question still could mean two things where it states "If any element matches then set a flag":

1. Elements at the same position, i.e $a[2] eq $b[2]
2. Values at any position, i.e. $a[3] eq $b[5]

For case 1, you might do this:

```
# iterate over all positions, and compare values at that position
my @matches = grep { $a[$_] eq $b[$_] } 0 .. $#a;

# set flag if there's any match at the same position 
my $flag = 1 if @matches;
```

For case 2, you might do that:

```
# make a hash of @a and check if any @b are in there
my %a = map { $_ => 1 } @a;
my @matches = grep { $a{$_} } @b;

# set flag if there's matches at any position 
my $flag = 1 if @matches;
```

Note that in the first case, @matches holds the indexes of where there are matching elements, and in the second case @matches holds the matching values in the order in which they appear in @b.