# In perl how to compare two arrays of objects (comparison logic being coded in a separate subroutine)?

Tags: arrays, perl, object, compare

Let me be specific to my problem instead of generalizing it and confusing the audience. In my code I have set of network addresses (members of object-group actually) stored in individual arrays. I would like to compare whether Group A is a subset of Group B.

I am using Net::IP module to parse the IP addresses and use "overlaps" sub-routine to determine if an element (could be individual IP or a subnet) is a superset of another element.

The challenge I am facing is in returning success status only if each element of Group A, belongs to any one element of Group B.

Here is a way I thought of and proceeding to try to code it likewise:

```
$status = "match";
foreach $ip (@group_a) {
  if a_in_b($ip,@group_b) #this sub-routine would be similar but with different comparison function
   {
   next;
   }
   else
   {
   $status = "no match"; 
   last;}
}
```

Please suggest me if there is a better way to do it, would love to pick up new techniques. The above technique doesn't look sound at all! As I was searching for for some solutions, some [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality) seem to suggest as if I could try using the smart match operator and overload it. But overloading is beyond my level of sophistication in perl, so kindly help!

EDIT:
Updated my code as per suggestion. Here is the working version (still need to add bits and pieces for error catching)

```
use Net::IP;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @subnet = ("10.1.128.0/24","10.1.129.0/24","10.1.130.0/24","10.1.108.4");
my @net = ("10.1.128.0/21","10.1.108.0/22");


sub array_subset {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    a_in_b ($_, @$y) or return '' foreach @$x;
    return 1;
};

sub a_in_b  {
  my $node1 = shift(@_);
  my @ip_list = @_;
  for my $node2 (@ip_list) {
    print $node2, "\n";
    my $ip1 = new Net::IP ($node1) || die;
    my $ip2 = new Net::IP ($node2) || die;
    print "$node1  $node2 \n";
    if ($ip1->overlaps($ip2)==$IP_A_IN_B_OVERLAP) {
      return 1;
    }

  }
  return "";
}

if (array_subset(\@subnet, \@net)) {
  print "Matches";
}else
{
  print "Doesn't match"
}
```

Comment: I'd like to see your `a_in_b` sub.

Comment: The structure of the code block is similar.. instead of having `a_in_b($ip,@group_b)` as condition statement, I will have `if ($ip1->overlaps($ip2)==$IP_A_IN_B_OVERLAP)` as the if condition. 
Would you still like to look at the entire sub-routine?

Comment: I am trying to get a sense of what your data is, and how you mean to compare it. I am not too good with IP and networks, but I do know perl.

Comment: Thanks. For the moment you can ignore intricacies of IP addressing, rather please look at the module Net::IP which does all the logic. The [overlaps](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm#overlaps) function compares two elements and returns a value ($IP_A_IN_B_OVERLAP being the checked value here). While the module allows to check one element vs another, I want to check one array vs another array, returning a value true only if all the comparisons yielded the value $IP_A_IN_B_OVERLAP. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I do not see that there is any way of getting around checking each array element against the others. Without getting into the nitty gritty, you cannot affect the comparison. Smart matching arrays is basically a text match, as I understand it. If you have large arrays, and/or the comparisons takes time, you can probably improve the performance through some tricks. Then it might be worth trying to combine ranges, and exclude values, analyze the data and find extreme values, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading ~~ is a bit of overkill. I would suggest using [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.30/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/all/;
if (all { a_in_b($_, @bignet) } @smallnet) {
     # do something
};
```

Or just rewrite your own code as a sub, and in a more perlish way:

```
sub array_subset {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    a_in_b ($_, @$y) or return '' foreach @$x;
    return 1;
};

# somewhere in the code 
if (array_subset(\@subnet, \@net)) {
    # do something
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It almost worked, but the pitfall was with my logic. If I have an array of supernets `(A,B)` and subnets `(A1,A2,A3,B1)` it returns no match because all the 4 subnets do not belong to the same supernet which is what the logic validates. I want it to return true for a case such as this: `A1,A2,A3 ⊆ A` & `B1 ⊆ B`

Comment: @Benny: Huh? As I can see, your logic (and hence mine) suggests testing *each* element of subnet to *the whole* supernet independently.

Comment: Oops, sorry looks like I have to check my code again. Will come back with the complete code. Thanks a bunch for your time!

Comment: I figured out it was a silly misplaced return statement. I placed it in the inner block instead of outer block. But now I am stuck with an error with Net:IP module, looks like it is not lax with the supplied IP address. I don't have control over the data source, so I need to know why it exactly failed and add appropriate validation code. Thanks a lot for your help so far!