# Perl: Sort characters within a string

Tags: arrays, string, perl, sorting

I have two strings, and I would like to test if they are anagrams of each other.

To test if string A is an anagram of string B, the characters of A and B are both sorted. If the resulting sorted strings match exactly, string A and string B are anagrams of each other.

I am `split`ing the strings up into character arrays, using Perl's `sort` routine, `join`ing the characters back together, and testing for string equality with `eq`:

```
sub anagram
{
  my ($s1, $s2) = @_;

  return (join '', sort { $a cmp $b } split(//, $s1)) eq
         (join '', sort { $a cmp $b } split(//, $s2));
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to convert between the scalar and array types (relying on `join` and `split`)? And if so, which method is more efficient?

Comment: Interesting read for the array comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality

Comment: You could also compare string length and return false if the string lengths are different, to avoid having to sort strings that are definitely not anagrams. For strings that are the same length, the length comparison is very quick, far quicker than split-sort-join, so any performance hit would be negligible.

Comment: Well, you can improve the performance by getting rid of the comparison function-you don't need it: `join '', sort split(//, $s1)`.

Comment: @derobert: You silly person, modern versions of perl (5.14.2 tested) actually optimize out the superfluous comparison function, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, I found a way to do much better. Assuming there aren't any bugs in my answer, which I'm not really sure of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both strings are variable, I don't think you can do much better. One alternative is to build a hash that maps characters to their counts, and then compare that the hashes have the same keys and values. I believe that this is O(n) instead of O(n log n) for your approach, but it would probably have worse actual performance except on very long strings.

If you want to compare variable strings to a fixed reference string, then perhaps the hash-based approach might pay dividends earlier, since you only need to hash the reference once.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I've found a way that's over 30 times faster—though, arguably, its cheating. I've included the Benchmark.pm code to benchmark it, since you're apparently not familiar with it.

The benchmark is:

```
           Rate  Join Cheat
Join    83294/s    --  -97%
Cheat 2580687/s 2998%    --
```

And the code. After the third line, I think you'll understand why its arguably cheating:

```
use v5.14;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
use Inline 'C';

sub an_join {
    my ($s1, $s2) = @_;
    return (join '', sort split(//, $s1)) eq
        (join '', sort split(//, $s2));
}

use constant {
    STR1 => 'abcdefghijklm',
    STR2 => 'abcdefghijkmm',
    STR3 => 'abcdefghijkml',
};

cmpthese(
    0,
    {
        'Join'  => 'an_join(STR1, STR2);  an_join(STR1, STR3)',
        'Cheat' => 'an_cheat(STR1, STR2); an_cheat(STR1, STR3)',
    });

__END__
__C__

int an_cheat(const char *a, const char *b) {
    unsigned char vec_a[26], vec_b[26];
    const char *p, *end;

    memset(vec_a, 0, sizeof(vec_a));
    memset(vec_b, 0, sizeof(vec_b));

    end = a+strlen(a);
    for (p = a; p < end; ++p)
        if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')
            ++vec_a[(*p)-'a'];
    end = b+strlen(b);
    for (p = b; p < end; ++p)
        if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')
            ++vec_b[(*p)-'a'];

    return 0 == memcmp(vec_a, vec_b, sizeof(vec_a));
}
```

Of course, its cheating because its not written in Perl—its in C. Also, it has limitations the Perl version doesn't (only works with lowercase ASCII characters being the most significant—it just ignores everything else). But if you really need speed, you can use cheating like this.

edit:

Extending to all of Latin1 (well, raw 8-bit characters, really). Also, I found that the compiler managed to optimize a simpler loop (without point arithmetic) better, and its easier to read too, so... Benchmark tells me that the lowercase-ASCII-only version is about 10% faster:

```
int an_cheat_l1b(const char *a, const char *b) {
    unsigned char vec_a[UCHAR_MAX], vec_b[UCHAR_MAX];
    size_t len, i;

    memset(vec_a, 0, sizeof(vec_a));
    memset(vec_b, 0, sizeof(vec_b));

    len = strlen(a);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        ++vec_a[((const unsigned char *)(a))[i]];
    len = strlen(b);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        ++vec_b[((const unsigned char *)(b))[i]];

    return 0 == memcmp(vec_a, vec_b, sizeof(vec_a));
}
```

Note that the advantage of the C version grows as the string gets longer—which is expected, since its Θ(n) as opposed to the Perl versions O(n·logn). Also the penalty for full Latin1 decreases, meaning that penalty is probably the memcmp.

Comment: even though this solution is somewhat stricter in where it can be applied, I admire the performance increase

Comment: is there a particular reason you are restricting the solution to lowercase ASCII? if your buffer was large enough to hold all of the ASCII values, you wouldn't need the if-condition or offset the vector indexes by 'a'

Comment: @ardnew: True, it'd be easy to extend to Latin1 (there would be trivial performance loss, I suspect). Extending to Perl characters (e.g., Unicode) would be very non-trivial. Of course, the Perl solution doesn't correctly handle Unicode (it fails to normalize), so, I guess that's OK... Will benchmark and update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I thought using smart matches to compare the arrays without needing to recreate the string would have to chance to outperform the OP's method

```
sub anagram_smatch {
    return [sort split//,$_[0]] ~~ [sort split//,$_[1]];
}
```

but the benchmarks don't bear that out.

```
         Rate smatch   join
smatch 1.73/s     --   -54%
join   3.72/s   116%     --
```

Comment: sorry but I'm not familiar with this benchmarking. how did you produce those results?

Comment: @ardnew: Looks like standard output from the [Benchmark module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid having to convert between the scalar and array types (relying on `join` and `split`)? And if so, which method is more efficient?

Since you ask these as two separate questions, I'll answer both.

Yes, there are ways to do this without creating an `@`array or `%`hash or whatnot, and I'll outline a few; but your way is more efficient than any of these.

One way is to treat a string as an array of characters by using [the `substr` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) (`$c = substr $s, 4, 1` sets `$c` to the fifth element of `$s`, and `substr($s, 4, 1) = $c` sets the fifth element of `$s` to `$c`), and implement any typical sorting algorithm on it.

Alternatively, I'm pretty sure you could implement bubble-sort using just regex-substitutions with `/e`.

Lastly, if you're willing to dispense with the sort-then-compare approach, you could write:

```
sub anagram
{
    my ($s1, $s2) = @_;
    while($s1 =~ m/\G(.)/s)
      { $s2 =~ s/\Q$1// or return ''; }
    return $s2 eq '';
}
```

But, again, the `split`-then-`join` is more efficient than any of these.