# How to do fast comparison of arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, is there a built in way to compare two arrays for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality)

I need to compare arrays with a function that should return:

- true if all elements are equal when compared pairwise
- true if all elements are equal **or the element in the first array is undefined** when compared pairwise
- false in all other cases

in other words, if the sub is called "comp":

```
@a = ('a', 'b', undef, 'c');
@b = ('a', 'b', 'f', 'c');
comp(@a, @b); # should return true
comp(@b, @a); # should return false

@a = ('a', 'b');
@b = ('a', 'b', 'f', 'c');
comp(@a, @b); # should return true
```

the obvious solution would be to do pairwise compares between the two arrays, but I'd like it to be faster than that, as the comparisons are run multiple times over a large set of arrays, the and the arrays may have many elements.

On the other hand, the contents of the arrays to be compared (i.e.: all the possible @b's) is pre-determined and does not change. The elements of the arrays do not have a fixed length, and there is no guarantee as to what chars they might contain (tabs, commas, you name it).

Is there a faster way to do this than pairwise comparison? Smart match won't cut it, as it returns true if *all* elements are equal (an therefore not if one is undef).

Could packing and doing bitwise comparisons be a strategy? It looks promising when I browse the docs for pack/unpack and vec, but I'm somewhat out of my depth there.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this has been answered already [on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality)

Comment: Any fast, built-in comparison will almost certainly not handle undefined elements the way you want, especially since it's asymmetric (undef is allowed in first array, but not second).

Comment: How can something faster than pairwise equality testing possibly exist?  If you know all possible arguments beforehand, index them somehow and build an array-of-arrays that contains the answer (true or false) for each possible pair.  You can do this either once at the start, or lazily as you go.  You would then call the function with the argument indices instead of the lists themselves.

Comment: This is **not** an exact duplicate.  The other asks about a comparison, and this is acting about speed for a particular case.

Comment: @nickisfat, you didn't bother to read question past second sentence, did you?

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov you didn't bother to read the thread I linked past the second answer, did you?

Comment: @nickisfat: I get it that it looks like iterating are faster than Array::Compare. My question is more specifically concerned with whether packing/unpacking and bitwise comparison could be a strategy. Smart match (~~) is not an option - as pointed out. I had checked the link you pointed to.

Comment: @Barmar: would making the test symmetric make it easier to answer? that's a constraint that could be removed.

Comment: @nickisfat, I did. Now would you kindly point me to answer that discusses pre-processing one of arrays to compare to optimize comparison time of big amount of elements (see "all the possible @b's) is pre-determined and does not change" part of question)?

Comment: No, making it symmetric wouldn't make it easier. The only thing that would make it easier is getting rid of the special case for undef. That means you can't do any general comparison, because these elements aren't actually equal.

Comment: I can think of a way to speed it up if the `@a` arrays (the ones with the `undef`s) don't change but `@b` does. But not the other way around.

Comment: Nobody's asked so I will... why the special case for undef?  Maybe that can be gotten rid of. What's the actual data being compared and why is it being stored this way? If it's so large that you're looking into micro-optimizing pair-wise comparison maybe what you need is a different data structure.

Comment: @Schwern: I am storing values that are indexed according to a set of features (say: weight, height, nationality, gender), and I want to summarize them according to one or more of these features (say: count the Italians that are 180cm tall; or average the weight of German women), and create sub-totals summarizing according to these features. I've tried using tree-like structures and multi-key hashes (a-la Hash::MultiKey), but I don't seem to get away from this array comparison. The number of possible combinations of all the features is ~10^5, the number of actually used ones closer to 3k.

Comment: @simone Have you considered putting them in a SQL database?  This is the sort of thing it does well and SQL has trinary logic where you can explicitly decide what to do with NULL.

Comment: @Schwern: yes, I have. However one of the key goals here is to be able to generate cross-tab reports, similar to those in Excel (without Excel - not available). I've tried DBIx::CrossTab, but it's API is way too complex. It _could_ be done in SQL, but it would be a nightmare of UNIONS and CASES, plus I wouldn't have access to custom aggregations like median, percentiles etc. (from Statistics::Descriptive), which is another desired feature that makes Excel pivot tables a non-solution

Comment: @simone Most decent SQL databases have extensive aggregation functions.  Here's the [Postgres aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) for example.  I'm pretty sure what you want can be done with a not too involved join.  Let me put something up.

Comment: How much faster? How long does it take now and how long do you think it should take?

Comment: A corollary to @AndyLester's comment: you want it faster than it is now, but how fast is it already?  You might be doing the comparison in a less than optimal way.  Perhaps you can post your code so we can comment on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl can compare lists of 10,000 pairwise elements in about 100ms on my Macbook, so first thing I'll say is to [profile your code](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf) to make sure this is actually the problem.

Doing some benchmarking, there's a few things you can do to speed things up.

- Make sure to bail on the first failure to match.

Assuming you have a lot of comparisons which don't match, this will save HEAPS of time.

- Check up front that the arrays are the same length.

If they arrays aren't the same length, they can never match.  Compare their sizes and return early if they're different.  This avoids needing to check this case over and over again inside the loop.

- Use an iterator instead of a C-style for loop.

Iterating pair-wise you'd normally do something like `for( my $idx = 0; $idx <= $#a; $idx += 2 )` but iterating over an array is faster than using a C-style for loop.  This is an optimization trick of Perl, its more efficient to do the work inside perl in optimized C than to do it in Perl code.  This gains you about 20%-30% depending on how you micro-optimize it.

```
for my $mark (0..$#{$a}/2) {
    my $idx = $mark * 2;
    next if !defined $a->[$idx] || !defined $b->[$idx];
    return 0 if $a->[$idx] ne $b->[$idx] || $a->[$idx+1] ne $b->[$idx+1];
}
return 1;
```

- Precompute the interesting indexes.

Since one set of pairs is fixed, you can produce an index of which pairs are defined.  This makes the iterator even simpler and faster.

```
state $indexes = precompute_indexes($b);

for my $idx ( @$indexes ) {
    next if !defined $a->[$idx];
    return 0 if $a->[$idx] ne $b->[$idx] || $a->[$idx+1] ne $b->[$idx+1];
}

return 1;
```

With no nulls this is a performance boost of 40%.  You get more beyond that the more nulls are in your fixed set.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;  # for state

# Compute the indexes of a list of pairs which are interesting for
# comparison: those with defined keys.
sub precompute_indexes {
    my $pairs = shift;

    die "Unbalanced pairs" if @$pairs % 2 != 0;

    my @indexes;
    for( my $idx = 0; $idx <= $#$pairs; $idx += 2 ) {
         push @indexes, $idx if defined $pairs->[$idx];
     }

    return \@indexes;
}

sub cmp_pairs_ignore_null_keys {
    my($a, $b) = @_;

    # state is like my but it will only evaluate once ever.
    # It acts like a cache which initializes the first time the
    # program is run.
    state $indexes = precompute_indexes($b);

    # If they don't have the same # of elements, they can never match.
    return 0 if @$a != @$b;

    for my $idx ( @$indexes ) {
        next if !defined $a->[$idx];
        return 0 if $a->[$idx] ne $b->[$idx] || $a->[$idx+1] ne $b->[$idx+1];
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I'm still convinced this is better to do in SQL with a self-join, but haven't worked that out.