# Comparison of two arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, comparison

I am trying to compare the content of two arrays and I need the final output as "Matched" or "Not Matched"
I have written the below code and it is giving the expected output. However, can anyone suggest me any other simple way of doing it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
 #Numeric scalar

my @array_1= (10,20,40,19);
my @array_2= (10,30,23,19);

print "@array_1\n";
my $count=0;
while ($count < scalar @array_1){
   for (@array_2) {
       if ($array_1[$count] == $array_2[$count]) {
        print "matched\n";
        $count++;} 
    else {
        print "Not matched\n";
        $count++;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you just need to know if they match, you might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality If this is an exercise in writing your own algorithm or a homework assignment, you're onto a very common approach - iterating through and failing with "Not Matched" when you find a non-match and resorting to "Matched" if you get through the whole thing without a non-match - but you're printing too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above solution is good.  Also you can use https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Compare module

> Array::Compare - Perl extension for comparing arrays. If you have two arrays and you want to know if they are the same or different, then Array::Compare will be useful to you.
> All comparisons are carried out via a comparator object.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Compare;

my @array_1= (10,20,40,19);
my @array_2= (10,30,23,19,66);

my $comp = Array::Compare->new;

if ($comp->compare(\@array_1, \@array_2)) {
  print "Arrays are the same (Matched)\n";
} else {
  print "Arrays are different (Not Matched)\n";
}
```

> Output

```
Arrays are different (Not Matched)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write down all the conditions that don't match first, and then show it as a match at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array_1 = (10,20,40,19);
my @array_2 = (10,30,23,19);

if (scalar @array_1 != scalar @array_2) {
  print "Not matched\n";
  exit 0;
}

while (my ($index, $elem) = each @array_1) {
  if ($elem != $array_2[$index]) {
    print "Not matched\n";
    exit 0;
  }
}

print "matched\n";
```

Comment: Your solution looks simple, thanks a lot Shingo..!!

Comment: `if (scalar @array_1 != scalar @array_2) {` can be simply `if (@array_1 != @array_2) {`